# How to set iTerm2 background color as none?

Tags: iterm2

[image]

I want this to be none, so the background image can show it's original color.

At first I try to make the color transparent，but there's no "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)" option.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In iTerm2 settings, go to Profiles, then Window. Change transparency to 90.[image]